# How the Class file is including in another file php using the namesapce and Use?

Tags: php, class, namespaces, composer-php

I have a class called as Errors in Errors.php

```
namespace MyClass;
    class Errors
    {
        private $_CODES = array(
            301 => array(
                "code"=> 301,
                "message"=> "User With ID Not Found",
                "type"=> "Error"
            )
        );


        public static function getError($code)
        {
            return $this->_CODES[$code];
        }
```

In Myclass.php i have

```
namespace MyClass;

use MyClass\Errors;

require'vendor/autoload.php';
```

inside the Myclass i have afunction and i am checking the errors

```
echo Errors::getError(301);
```

It shows class Myclass not found error

```
Fatal error: Class 'Myclass\Errors' not found in /var/www/Myclass/Myclass.php
```

what have i missed here?

Comment: where did you stored `Errors.php` ?

Comment: show the code in `autoload.php`

Comment: require_once __DIR__ . '/composer' . '/autoload_real.php';

return ComposerAutoloaderInitddb04cf330f79dfb9cb9654960258d63::getLoader();

Answer (score 0):

You have to include your `Errors.php`

Comment: he his using composer's autoloader

Comment: autoloading was meant to get rid of explicit usage of `include` , `require` for class loading

Comment: No question about it. And still, `Errors.php` has to be included, but for now it seems to be not.

Answer (score 0):

The composer autoloader is compatible to the [PSR4](https://github.com/php-fig/fig-standards/blob/master/proposed/psr-4-autoloader/psr-4-autoloader.md) standard. In your current solution the file `Errors.php` must be placed in a sub folder called `MyClass`. [Read more](https://getcomposer.org/doc/04-schema.md#autoload)

Answer (score 0):

Seems you are using Composer's autoloader.
Did you modify your "composer.json" to make it loads for you?

Maybe something like:

> "autoload": { "classmap": ["path/to/your/source/directory"] }

Or [PSR-4 style which is described in official documentation](https://getcomposer.org/doc/01-basic-usage.md#autoloading)

Answer (score 0):

This Issue is solved. Errors.php looks like below.

```
class Errors{
    private static $_CODES = array(
        301 => array(
          "code"=> 301, 
          "message"=> "User With ID Not Found", 
          "type"=> "Error"
        )
    ); 

    public static function getError($code) { 
        return self::$_CODES[$code]['message'];
    }
}
```

and i have added require_once "Errors.php"; in MyClass.php file, now i can call the function `echo Errors::getError(301)`